# Python calculator program operator input EOF error

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, calculator, operations

I learned python several years ago and I decided I should revisit the language and brush up my skills. I am creating a basic calculator program, and embarrassingly, I am having issues taking in the +,-,*.. operators. My code right now is just trying to print whatever operator I have inputed.

```
op = input("Enter your operation")

print(op)
```

When I compile the program with terminal using "python first.py" I get the following error:

[image]

But when I run the program using "python3 first.py" there is no error and when I print out op I get the correct operation I entered. Why is this happening and what is different in the versions that is giving me the error? Thanks for your guys explanation!

EDIT: I am assuming the python terminal command uses python version 2 and python3, obviously, means python version 3

Comment: If you want to read a string, use `raw_input` in Python2 or `input` in Python 3. `input` in Python 2 is immediately `eval`'d by the parser (tries to execute what you type as a statement)

Comment: Perfect explanation, Thank you!